# How to wrap each paragraph in a command using ConTeXt?

Tags: context, paragraphs

I’m typesetting a document partly translated from german into french. To do so, I created a \voc command, designed to:

1. Put the word into a register.
2. Display the word in bold.
3. Display its translation on the right side of the page. I used the “localfootnote” and the “paragraphs” mechanisms.

To be effective, the document needs the \dispvoc command at the beginning of each paragraph.

Here is a MWE :

```
\setuppapersize[A4, landscape][A4, landscape]

\defineregister[vocabulaire]
\setupheadtext[vocabulaire={Vokabeln}]
\define[4]\voc{\vocabulaire[#2]{#3}{\bf #1}\postponenotes\footnote{{\bf #3 :} #4}}

\defineparagraphs[vocparagraphs][n=2, tolerance=stretch, distance=2em]
\setupparagraphs[vocparagraphs][1][width=17cm]

\setupfootnotes[location=text]

\define[1]\dispvoc{\startlocalfootnotes \startvocparagraphs #1 \vocparagraphs \placelocalfootnotes \stopvocparagraphs \stoplocalfootnotes}

\starttext

\dispvoc{
Wer bei Rechtsextremen nach Widersprüchen, Antidemokratentum und Sehnsucht nach Kulturkampf sucht, muss \voc{wahrlich}{wahrlich}{wahrlich}{vraiment} kein Archäologe sein. Wer aber auf der Suche nach einem politischen Konzept für gesellschaftliche Probleme ist, wird beim Graben eher auf eine Wasserader stoßen denn auf eine Idee. Deshalb wundert sich die Gegenöffentlichkeit und fragt sich, ja Himmel, warum werden sie bloß gewählt? Die Rechten tun doch bloß so, als wären sie die Abis der Abgehängten. Gleich danach folgt die Schuldfrage. Wer ist schuld daran, dass die Rechten in Europa \voc{überhaupt}{überhaupt}{überhaupt}{en général} einen Fuß auf den Boden \voc{bekamen}{bekommen}{einen Fuß auf den Boden bekommen}{avoir du succès}?}

\dispvoc{Man kann die Frage auch einmal \voc{andersherum}{andersherum}{andersherum}{dans l'autre sens} stellen. Was machen Front National, AfD, FPÖ und Co \voc{eigentlich}{eigentlich}{eigentlich}{au juste} richtig gut? Und das ist nun der \voc{Zeitpunkt}{Zeitpunkt}{der Zeitpunkt}{le moment}, da man, nachdem man viel über politische Inhalte sprach, auch über den Duktus des Rechtsextremen sprechen muss. Armin Thurnher, Gründer und Chefredakteur der Wiener Wochenzeitung Falter erfand vor eineinhalb Jahrzehnten den Begriff Feschismus für Jörg Haider. Das Wort setzt sich zusammen aus fesch und Faschismus. Seitdem \voc{bestätigt}{bestätigen}{sich bestätigen}{se vérifier (dans les faits)} sich diese Beobachtung. Eine Österreicherin sagte vor einigen Tagen in den ZDF-Nachrichten über Norbert Hofer ungefähr so: " .. und überhaupt. Gut sieht er aus. Wer so ausschaut, kann nichts Schlechtes wollen." Damit hat sie beschrieben, was alle modernen rechten Demagogen der Neuzeit anstreben. Anti-Establishment sein und dabei super established aussehen.}

\stoptext
```

Here is the result:

[image: The result]

I have two questions:

1. How can begin each paragraph with this \dispvoc command **automatically**?
2. How can I avoid footnotes numbers restarting from one (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 instead of 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1-> 2 -> 3)?

Comment: Probably Lua is the way to go.

Comment: Have you tried using margin notes rather that tables (essentially, paragraphs mechanism is a table).

Comment: **1)** Your example code is not a MWE, as it contains lots of text which has nothing to do with the actual question. Please fix that. **2)** Can you further explain what you mean by your first question? Currently its very vague, IMHO

Comment: @toogley

You’re right, it’s not strictly speaking a MWE. However, I think showing two paragraphs helps understanding my problem. What I had in mind in my first question was a way to apply \dispvoc to each paragraph automatically. Here is what I want to write:
`Paragraph 1 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.

Paragraph 2 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.`

Here is what I want ConTeXt to understand:

`\dispvoc{Paragraph 1 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.}

\dispvoc{Paragraph 2 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.}`

Answer (score 4):

You can automate the placement of the notes with the combination of the layer mechanism the `\setupparagraphintro` command.

```
\setuppapersize[A4,landscape]

\setuplayout
  [width=18cm,
   rightmargin=6cm]

\setupnote    [footnote][location=text]
\setupnotation[footnote][numbercommand=,alternative=serried]

\definelayer[notelayer][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=notelayer]

\newcounter\notecounter

\starttexdefinition unexpanded ParagraphNote

  \BeforePar
    {\increment\notecounter
     \dontleavehmode\xypos{note:\notecounter}}

  \AfterPar
    {\par
     \setlayerframed
       [notelayer]
       [x=\dimexpr\textwidth+\MPx{note:\notecounter}+\rightmargindistance\relax,
        y=\dimexpr\paperheight-\MPy{note:\notecounter}-\strutht\relax]
       [ frame=off,
         align=flushleft,
         width=\rightmarginwidth,
        offset=none]
       {\placenotes[footnote][before=,after=]}}

  \GetPar

\stoptexdefinition

\setupparagraphintro[each][\ParagraphNote]

\starttext

Wer bei Rechtsextremen nach Widersprüchen, Antidemokratentum und Sehnsucht
nach Kulturkampf sucht, muss wahrlich\footnote{wahrlich: vraiment} kein
Archäologe sein. Wer aber auf der Suche nach einem politischen Konzept für
gesellschaftliche Probleme ist, wird beim Graben eher auf eine Wasserader
stoßen denn auf eine Idee. Deshalb wundert sich die Gegenöffentlichkeit
und fragt sich, ja Himmel, warum werden sie bloß gewählt? Die Rechten tun
doch bloß so, als wären sie die Abis der Abgehängten. Gleich danach folgt
die Schuldfrage. Wer ist schuld daran, dass die Rechten in Europa
überhaupt\footnote{überhaupt: en général} einen Fuß auf den Boden
bekamen\footnote{einen Fuß auf den Boden bekommen: avoir du succès}?

Man kann die Frage auch einmal andersherum\footnote{andersherum: dans l'autre sens}
stellen. Was machen Front National, AfD, FPÖ und Co eigentlich\footnote{eigentlich: au juste}
richtig gut? Und das ist nun der Zeitpunkt\footnote{der Zeitpunkt: le moment},
da man, nachdem man viel über politische Inhalte sprach, auch über den Duktus
des Rechtsextremen sprechen muss. Armin Thurnher, Gründer und Chefredakteur
der Wiener Wochenzeitung Falter erfand vor eineinhalb Jahrzehnten den Begriff
Feschismus für Jörg Haider. Das Wort setzt sich zusammen aus fesch und Faschismus.
Seitdem bestätigt\footnote{sich bestätigen: se vérifier (dans les faits)} sich diese
Beobachtung. Eine Österreicherin sagte vor einigen Tagen in den ZDF-Nachrichten
über Norbert Hofer ungefähr so: " .. und überhaupt. Gut sieht er aus. Wer so ausschaut,
kann nichts Schlechtes wollen." Damit hat sie beschrieben, was alle modernen rechten
Demagogen der Neuzeit anstreben. Anti-Establishment sein und dabei super established aussehen.

\stoptext
```

[image: Margin notes]